# Fixing base64 encoding error in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I'm trying to access an API which has requires authentication. However I keep getting the error which reads " a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' " for the base64encode line.

```
user = input("user: example")
password = getpass.getpass("password: example1234")
authCred = base64.b64encode(user + ":" + password)
```

I tried to change the code to:

```
user = input("user: example")
password = getpass.getpass("password: example1234")
authCred = base64.b64encode(user.encode('ascii') + ":" + password.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
```

But then I get the error "can't concat str to bytes"

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted fix didn't work because you tried to mix encoded and non-encoded strings.

Make a string that is the username plus a colon plus the password, then encode that *whole* string:

```
userpass = user + ":" + pass
authCred = base64.b64encode(userpass.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Alternately, use `b':'` for the colon when assembling the results afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

does encoding it as bytes help?

authcred = bytes(authcred , encoding= 'utf-8')